# How to read MPP file into ASP.NET (C#) without any software installed

Tags: ms-project, mpxj

My colleague has asked me to import .MPP data into SQL Server database.

Here the twist is that I DON'T have any software installed for managing .MPP file.

After googling some time, I found that MPXJ can help me to some extent. Hence, I have tried to download, but, could not because of company security policy restrictions. For example: I can open the following link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpxj/files/

But, I cannot click on the link to download the software as the page has been blocked by company security policy.

Hence, can anybody please suggest whether there is anyway to import .MPP data into SQL Server database anyway?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Without MS Project installed, or a library like MPXJ... you won't have much luck. You could try talking to your IT department about the download, or download it at home and email it to yourself at work, or bring it in on a USB key... lots of options!

Comment: Is this a one time thing, or you need to create a program that does this whenever you need it?

Answer (score 1):

I've read mpp file into ASP.Net (C#). Finally, I've used MPXJ library. MPXJ is a open source library and free for all.

Another way to import mpp file use [oledb](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aptKf4qXhcOoJ%3awww.msproject.com/OLEDB.htm+microsoft+project+mpp+ole+db+provider&hl=en&ct=clnk&cd=3&gl=us), however, it's not easy.
I think you should try talking to your IT department about the download and use it.

Please let me know if you need any helps.

Tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/738026/Accessing-MPP-File-using-MPXJ-Lib-using-Csharp